# How can I build a network of 5 smartphones that log accelerometer data into a computer?

Tags: sensors, data-transfer, interoperability

I would like to build a network consisting of 5 smartphones (preferably Android, if it makes any difference) that log synchronized accelerometer data into a computer (like a data-logger). How can I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

Some more details:
- the preferred sampling frequency is 50Hz. Depending on the quality of the accelerometers, this high frequency might not make sense. However, a sampling frequency below 10 Hz would not be useful.
- Data from all accelerometers needs to be synchronized. The logged data should preferably be in the following format: Time Acceleration11 Acceleration12...Acceleration53;
Where Acceleration11 is acceleration in device 1, direction 1 (say, X-direction).

I am a newbie in electronics and IoT, so please consider this fact in your answer. For instance, please avoid using abbreviations without explaining them and please provide some guidance how to practically achieve what you are suggesting.

Comment: What is wrong with basic WiFi?

Comment: publish the data to an MQTT server or send the data to google sheets

Comment: @hardillb --> how do you use basic WiFi to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: @jsotola --> can you please elaborate? Will I get synchronized data this way?

Comment: You connect all the phones and the computer to the same WiFi network. Job done

Comment: You current question is far too broad to get anything more detailed than I have provided.

Comment: Why do you think it is broad? I think it is very specific: I just want to log data from 5 smartphones into a computer (like a data-logger). If I connect all the phones and the computer to the same Wifi network, the job is not done, because I can't log data into the computer, I will merely share the same network, browse the internet etc. How do I log accelerometer data into the computer? And how do I make sure data from 5 devices is synchronized?

Comment: I'm saying that question doesn't have enough detail to comment on anything else. You've not said what the frequency of the readings are, what the consequences of missing a reading are or if a reading arrives late.  There just isn't enough information to say anything more

Comment: If the frequencies are high, go MQTT and a raspi server. If not, you can timestamp your data and HTTP it to a cloud server.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I modified the question and its details based on your comments. I invite you to read once again the question and the description. @MarcoTulioSouza, how do I timestamp my data and HTTP them to a cloud server? Do I need to write an app? Can you please elaborate your answer? I think you have the answer to my question, but as I said, I am a newbie and would appreciate some more details.

Comment: Just a reminder to all above: if you've got an answer, please post it below rather than as a comment. The comments above are for asking for clarification rather than for providing part-answers. Thanks.

Comment: @BIal, I will elaborate the answer when I have some time. With the details you provided, I think I can give you some good advice. I have some projects working like what you need.

Comment: @Marco, thanks a lot. Looking forward to your answer.

Comment: @BIal, I have posted an answer. Note that it does not consider the use of bluetooth. If the smartphones are close to each other, it would be a very nice possibility. If needed, I can edit the answer in order to talk a little bit about that. Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you very much @MarcoTulioSouza!  You answered my question. I will have to do some research in order to implement it though. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronize data from different devices is always a hard task. In your favor, you are using smartphones. You can manage to have accurate microsecond precision on your timestamps in this scenario.

First of all, we need to think about the communication. The easier way I could think, that would require the least programming and hardware works like this:

1. The phones are running an app which samples the accelerometer data, timestamp them with the best precision you can and then HTTP request them to a webserver.
2. The webserver consists of a RPi running LAMP. A PHP script receives the request, and place the data in a table using mySQL.
3. Your front end consists of a simple webpage on which javascript gets the data from the database and do the according processing on it.

Now let's talk about #1.

In my opinion, you have two ways of timestamping your data. The easy way and the hard way:

The simplest way is to use a external source, such as [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/). Another very simple way is to use your GPS timestamps, which are pretty acurate.
The hard way is to go for clock sync. These are hard to achieve.

*But*,

there is a [tool](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/set-your-android-atomic-time-for-perfectly-synced-clock-0170500/) to help you with that.

The webserver is pretty straightforward. Get a RPi, go for LAMP, you are done. PHP simple server with mysqli and you are done. The internet is full of tutorials.

Once you have your data in the database and properly timestamped according to your precision, parse it and do whatever you need with that. If the timestamp matches, there is your synchronized data.

Please note that this is a very simple approach with some extensive drawbacks depending on how precise the synchronization should be, But this may give you a head start for the task.